# How to set default arrow tips in Chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

I want, for example, `\arrow{->}` (and `\arrow{<->}`, `\arrow{<=>}`... too) to draw an arrow with the "stealth" style tip. How can I do that?

Comment: As from v1.2 2015-10-08 apparently `\setarrowdefault{,,,-stealth}` is possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

As **clemens** mentions in [`a comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269655/how-to-set-default-arrow-tips-in-chemfig/269657?noredirect=1#comment656433_269657), from v1.2 2015-10-08  `\setarrowdefault{,,,<arrow tip>}` is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\setarrowdefault{,,,-Stealth}
\schemestart 
A\arrow B\arrow{<-} C\arrow{<->}[,,red] D\arrow{-/>}[45,2,thick] E
\schemestop

\setarrowdefault{,,,-{Bar[length=10pt]}}
\schemestart 
A\arrow B\arrow{<-} C\arrow{<->}[,,red] D\arrow{-/>}[45,2,thick] E
\schemestop

\setarrowdefault{,,,-{Circle[red]}}
\schemestart 
A\arrow B\arrow{<-} C\arrow{<->}[,,red] D\arrow{-/>}[45,2,thick] E
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Older versions

The arrow tip for those arrows is defined by `chemfig` as `CF@full` and the original definition is (See `chemfig.tex`):

```
\pgfarrowsdeclare{CF@full}{CF@full}%
    {\CF@arrow@size\dimexpr2.5pt+2.5\pgflinewidth\relax
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{-\CF@arrow@size}\pgfarrowsrightextend{.5\pgflinewidth}}%
    {\CF@arrow@size\dimexpr2.5pt+2.5\pgflinewidth\relax
    \pgfsetdash{}\z@\pgfsetroundjoin\pgfsetroundcap
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint\z@\z@}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\CF@arrow@size}{.5\CF@arrow@size}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.5\CF@arrow@size}\z@}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\CF@arrow@size}{-.5\CF@arrow@size}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint\z@\z@}%
    \pgfusepathqfillstroke}
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find any short mechanism to change the arrow tip. I present to possible solutions below.

One option would be then to replace the arrow definition for that of `Stealth` (to be found in `pfgcorearrows.code.tex`); this will change all arrow tips using `CF@full` (in particular, those mentioned in the question):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{CF@full}{CF@full}%
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-3\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+5\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\schemestart 
A\arrow B\arrow{<-} C\arrow{<->}[,,red] D\arrow{-/>}[45,2,thick] E
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Another option is to directly redefine `->`, `<-`, `<->` (and all other desired arrows) to replace `CF@full` with `Stealth`; doing this through a command allows you to easily change to any desired tip:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand\MyArrowTip{Stealth}

\makeatletter
\definearrow3{->}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#3}%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-\MyArrowTip](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node);%
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}+\CF@arrow@start@node{#2}{0.5}-\CF@arrow@end@node
}

\definearrow3{<-}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#3}%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,\MyArrowTip-](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node);%
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}+\CF@arrow@start@node{#2}{0.5}-\CF@arrow@end@node
}

\definearrow5{-/>}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#3}%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-\MyArrowTip](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)%
        coordinate[midway,shift=(\CF@arrow@current@angle:-1pt)](midway@i)%
        coordinate[midway,shift=(\CF@arrow@current@angle:1pt)](midway@ii)%
        coordinate[at=(midway@i),shift=(\ifx\@empty#4\@empty225\else#4+180\fi+\CF@arrow@current@angle:\ifx\@empty#5\@empty5pt\else#5\fi)](line@start)%
        coordinate[at=(midway@i),shift=(\ifx\@empty#4\@empty45\else#4\fi+\CF@arrow@current@angle:\ifx\@empty#5\@empty5pt\else#5\fi)](line@end)%
        coordinate[at=(midway@ii),shift=(\ifx\@empty#4\@empty225\else#4+180\fi+\CF@arrow@current@angle:\ifx\@empty#5\@empty5pt\else#5\fi)](line@start@i)%
        coordinate[at=(midway@ii),shift=(\ifx\@empty#4\@empty45\else#4\fi+\CF@arrow@current@angle:\ifx\@empty#5\@empty5pt\else#5\fi)](line@end@i);
    \draw(line@start)--(line@end);%
    \draw(line@start@i)--(line@end@i);%
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}+\CF@arrow@start@node{#2}{0.5}-\CF@arrow@end@node
}

\definearrow3{<->}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#3}%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,\MyArrowTip-\MyArrowTip](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node);%
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}+\CF@arrow@start@node{#2}{0.5}-\CF@arrow@end@node
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\schemestart 
A\arrow B\arrow{<-} C\arrow{<->}[,,red] D\arrow{-/>}[45,2,thick] E
\schemestop

\renewcommand\MyArrowTip{Bar[length=10pt]}
\schemestart 
A\arrow B\arrow{<-} C\arrow{<->}[,,red] D\arrow{-/>}[45,2,thick] E
\schemestop

\renewcommand\MyArrowTip{Circle[red]}
\schemestart 
A\arrow B\arrow{<-} C\arrow{<->}[,,red] D\arrow{-/>}[45,2,thick] E
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice, however, that all other arrow types were not redefined so this might lead to inconsistencies in arrow tips in your diagrams.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think it was so complicated, I tried with a simple `\setarrowdefault` before giving up and posting here..

Comment: As from v1.2 2015-10-08 apparently `\setarrowdefault{,,,-stealth}` is possible

Comment: @ArchStanton An update to the package has been made and now `Stealth` can be selected in an easier way (see **clemens** comment above and updated answer).

Comment: @clemens Thanks for the tip. I updated the answer. For more general arrows (Bar, Circle), however, `\setarrowdefault` won't work (although I wouldn't expect those arrow tips to be used in real applications, though). Thanks, again.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina `\setarrowdefault{,,-Bar}` works for me...

Comment: @clemens Ha! You're right. I don't know why my previous tests didn't work. Will corrcet the update.