# How to use different arrow tips and typs in \definearrow in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

Users @runiq and @clemens showed in [Easy way to write below arrow (\arrow{-U>}) in chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74763/easy-way-to-write-below-arrow-arrow-u-in-chemfig) how to define a new arrowtype in chemfig using `\definearrow` which works great. I am not a tikz expert, but can anybody give me a hint of how I can change the arrow tips so that I have a horizontal equilibrium arrow (<=>) and an arched double arrow (<->) below? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't know about `\definearrow`, but I *do* however for `\setarrowdefault` is an option that has countless possibilities (source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269655/how-to-set-default-arrow-tips-in-chemfig). I would answer myself, but as this topic is widely covered already, it would be blatant plagiarism even if all of my code was typed independently. And just a small hint (I don't know if you're aware), we get `<=>` arrow with `\arrow{<=>}`. For further reading, I suggest you the `chemfig` manual: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Gregor-Perčič for pointing me into the right direction. The file chemfig.tex mentioned in [How to set default arrow tips in Chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269655/how-to-set-default-arrow-tips-in-chemfig) is a good resource, there is a number of `\definearrow` commands in there so that one can see of how the definition of new arrows works. I expanded on the arrow `-X>` defined by @runiq in [Easy way to write below arrow (\arrow{-U>}) in chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74763/easy-way-to-write-below-arrow-arrow-u-in-chemfig) and named it `<X>`, you can see the result below. Thanks again for all your help.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\makeatletter
\definearrow{9}{<X>}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#7}%
    %\expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)node[midway](Xarrow@arctangent){};%
\path[allow upside down](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)%
            node[pos=0,sloped,yshift=1pt](\CF@arrow@start@node @u0){}%
            node[pos=0,sloped,yshift=-1pt](\CF@arrow@start@node @d0){}%
            node[pos=1,sloped,yshift=1pt](\CF@arrow@start@node @u1){}%
            node[pos=1,sloped,yshift=-1pt](\CF@arrow@start@node @d1){}%
            node[midway,yshift=1pt](Xarrow@arctangent@u){}%
            node[midway,yshift=-1pt](Xarrow@arctangent@d){};%
    \begingroup
        \pgfarrowharpoontrue
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style](\CF@arrow@start@node @u0)--(\CF@arrow@start@node @u1);%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style](\CF@arrow@start@node @d1)--(\CF@arrow@start@node @d0);%
    \endgroup
\edef\CF@tmp@str{\ifx\@empty#1\@empty[draw=none]\fi}%
\expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Xarrow@arctangent@u)%
    arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\ifx\@empty#8\@empty0.333\else#8\fi,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle-90,%
    delta angle=-\ifx\@empty#9\@empty60\else#9\fi]node(Xarrow1@start){};
\edef\CF@tmp@str{[\ifx\@empty#2\@empty draw=none,\fi-CF]}%
\expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Xarrow@arctangent@u)%
    arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\ifx\@empty#8\@empty0.333\else#8\fi,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle-90,%
    delta angle=\ifx\@empty#9\@empty60\else#9\fi]node(Xarrow1@end){};
\edef\CF@tmp@str{[\ifx\@empty#4\@empty draw=none,\fi-CF]}%
\expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Xarrow@arctangent@d)%
    arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\ifx\@empty#8\@empty0.333\else#8\fi,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle+90,%
    delta angle=\ifx\@empty#9\@empty60\else#9\fi]node(Xarrow2@start){};
\edef\CF@tmp@str{[\ifx\@empty#5\@empty draw=none,\fi-CF]}%
\expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Xarrow@arctangent@d)%
    arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\ifx\@empty#8\@empty0.333\else#8\fi,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle+90,%
    delta angle=-\ifx\@empty#9\@empty60\else#9\fi]node(Xarrow2@end){};
\edef\CF@tmp@str{\if\string-\expandafter\@car\detokenize{#7.}\@nil-\else+\fi}%
\CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0}\CF@tmp@str{Xarrow1@start}{#2}{1}\CF@tmp@str{Xarrow1@end}%
\CF@arrow@display@label{#3}{0.5}\CF@tmp@str\CF@arrow@start@node{}{}{}\CF@arrow@end@node%
\edef\CF@tmp@str{\if\string-\expandafter\@car\detokenize{#7.}\@nil+\else-\fi}%
\CF@arrow@display@label{#4}{0}\CF@tmp@str{Xarrow2@start}{#5}{1}\CF@tmp@str{Xarrow2@end}%
\CF@arrow@display@label{#6}{0.5}\CF@tmp@str\CF@arrow@start@node{}{}{}\CF@arrow@end@node%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
        \begin{equation}
          \setatomsep{1.3em}
          \schemestart
            \chemname{\chemfig*{CH_3-C(=[::90]O)-{\color{blue}^{13}C}OO^{-}}}{pyruvate}
            \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<X>[][][\footnotesize alanine transaminase (ALT)][\footnotesize glutamate][\footnotesize $\alpha$-ketoglutarate][]}[,2.7]
            \chemname{\chemfig*{CH_3-CH(-[::90]NH_3)-    {\color{blue}^{13}C}OO^{-}}}{alanine}
          \schemestop
        \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Your “MWE” gives `! Undefined control sequence.` because you're missing `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. BTW: the *first* paragraph in the current manual reads “_**Arrow tips** The default arrow tip in ChemFig, called “`CF`”, is now defined with the macro `\pgfdeclarearrow` and is based on the «`Stealth`» tip. For this, th “`arrows.meta`”e library is loaded. Therefore, “`CF`” and “`Stealth`” tips have the same custumization options. The arrow tip can now be defined with `\setarrowdefault.`_” :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this copy&paste error, I added the missing `\makeatletter` statement to the code above. However, I don't think that the arrow above could be reproduced just using the \setarrowdefault command.